# mongodb previous releases dates

Tags: mongodb

I'm need an information about the time when some important version of mongodb was released. Some kind of timeline which helps me to map mongodb books with actual mongodb version for that moment.

Does anybody know that or maybe have some historical data?

Comment: You might want to sing up their newsletter. It's on the official site, right-top corner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Over here](http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/osx/x86_64) is the release list for osx.

You can get the list for another os by clicking "list" at the bottom of this [page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) for your os.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB provides a [list of past and future versions](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:versions-panel&subset=-1) on their website